# MySQL re-arrange/re-order row position if a column value occurred once

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table like in the example below,

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Name              |  Score    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | John              | 80        |
| 2      | John              | 75        |
| 3      | Daniel            | 70        |
| 4      | Lisa              | 60        |
| 5      | Joe               | 74        |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I would like to select the names and position them as per their scores but still make sure that if the same name occurs twice, then be able to push it down (so that in the above example John does not appear twice right after each other).As for example when I retrieve it, it should come in the format below:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Name              |  Score    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | John              | 80        |
| 2      | Joe               | 74        |
| 3      | Daniel            | 70        |
| 4      | Lisa              | 60        |
| 5      | John              | 75        |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

If such a query is possible then can we even control how far below the row is pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  @RN := @RN + 1 AS ID,Name,Score FROM 
(SELECT T1.Name, T1.Score, count(*) as RN1 
 FROM TableName T1
 JOIN TableName T2 ON T1.Name = T2.Name AND T1.Score <= T2.Score
 GROUP BY T1.Name, T1.Score) TempTable,(SELECT @RN := 0) R
ORDER BY RN1, Score DESC
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME    SCORE
1   John    80
2   Joe     74
3   Daniel  70
4   Lisa    60
5   John    75
```

Sample Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc69d/13).

**Explanation:**

If you execute the inner query, you will get the records ordered by score desc along with a column RN1 as 2 for John and 1 for others. It is basically a ranking system. Then we will order by the result based on RN1 column. So you will get the result with name and score.

The outer query is used to add the ID column (it is a row number column actually).

Answer (score 1):

My inclination would be to aggregate the data and count the number of rows and maximum score for each name.  Then use this information for `order by`:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select name, max(score) as maxs, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by name
     ) tt
     on t.name = tt.name
order by (case when t.score = t.maxscore then 1 else 2 end),
         score desc;
```

This should work if there are no duplicates on the maximum score -- as is true of your actual data.  One way to fix this is to use the id instead:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.score
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.id
              from table tt
              where tt.name = t.name
              order by score desc
              limit 1
             ) as maxscore_id
      from table t
     ) t
order by (id = maxscore_id) desc, score desc;
```